# Getting the current item number or index when using will_paginate in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination

I have a rails app that stores movies watched, books read, etc. The index page for each type  lists paged collections of all its items, using will_paginate to bring back 50 items per page. When I output the items I want to display a number to indicate what item in the total collection it is. The numbering should be reversed as the collection is displayed with most recent first. This might not relate to will_paginate but rather some other method of calculation.

I will be using the same ordering in multiple types so it will need to be reusable. As an example, say I have 51 movies. The first item of the first page should display:

> 1. Fight Club - Watched: 30th Dec 2010

Whilst the last item on the page should display:

> 1. The Matrix - Watched: 3rd Jan 2010

The paged collection is available as an instance variable e.g. @movies, and @movies.count will display the number of items in the paged collection. So if we're on page 1, movies.count == 50, whilst on page 2 @movies.count == 1. Using Movie.count would give 51.

If the page number and page size can be accessed the number could be calculated so how can they be returned? Though I'm hopeful there is something that already exists to handle this calculation!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It feels a bit hacky, but I've come up with a working solution. I create an instance variable in the view:

```
@count = @movies.total_entries - @movies.offset
```

Then when rendering each movie I output @count and decrement it.

As per my previous example with 51 items on two pages: total_entries == 51, and offset == 0 (page 1) or 50 (page 2).

Comment: Maybe to avoid getting negative number you could add something along the lines of `@count >= 0 ? @count : 0`

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the built-in function:

```
<%= page_entries_info @posts %>  #-> Displaying posts 6 - 10 of 26 in total
```

Comment: I saw that, but unless I can get the individual numbers out it won't help solve this problem. I have come up with a solution, but I don't feel it is a great one. The calculation would need to be repeated every time it is used.